# Bro IDS signature_match trigger

Tags: signature, bro, zeek

I am new to BRO and just started to test signature on BRO. I have one script, main.bro, and a signature file, protosigs.sig. The idea is to compare the signature and do something within the rewritten event function - signature_match. I tried to use the following measure to test a pcap file but the test didn't generate a notice.log. It seemed the function - signature_match wasn't get called. Can anyone let me know what's going on here? Many thanks!

How I test the script and signature:

```
bro -r ./bittorrent.Transfer.pcap ./main.bro -s ./protosigs.sig
```

My signature:

```
signature torrent-request-tcp {
    ip-proto == tcp
    payload /^\x13/
    tcp-state originator
    event "torrent-request-tcp"
}
```

My script - main.bro:

```
@load base/frameworks/notice
@load base/frameworks/signatures/main
@load base/utils/addrs
@load base/utils/directions-and-hosts

#@load-sigs ./protosigs.sig

module bittorrent;

export {

    redef enum Notice::Type += {
        Torrent,
    };
}


event signature_match(state: signature_state, msg: string, data: string)
    &priority=-5
    {print "Triggerd!"; //at least this one should be triggered, but..
    if ( /torrent/ in state$sig_id ) 
        {
            print "TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT";
        NOTICE([$note=bittorrent::Torrent,
                $msg="Torrent whatsoever",
                $sub=data,
                $conn=state$conn,
                $identifier=fmt("%s%s", state$conn$id$orig_h, state$conn$id$resp_h)]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I feel like your signature is super restrictive.  You realize that the signature isn't checking for a 0x13 at the start of each packet, it's looking for 0x13 at the beginning of the stream, right?  I suspect your signature never matches, which is why signature_match is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Xifeng your setup seems to work fine here (putting aside the "//" comment delimiter, where you'll want "#" instead). The signature should be fine too, since the BitTorrent protocol indeed starts with 0x13 by the originator. The pcap I used is this one:

https://pcapr.net/view/gerald/2009/0/3/10/Comcast_Bittorrent_no_RST.pcap.html

Are you sure your pcap is okay? Make sure it contains the TCP handshake so Bro can properly bootstrap the connection state.